# How to bring animated effects in background in Android app?

Tags: android, animation, background, effects

I am trying to add an animation ( not sure if that would be an appropriate word ) of beach waves when my app loads with its first screen.I am developing a holiday app and  have already set an image (a static image of sand ) as the background.I am expecting to have the sand image as background and have an effect of the waves hitting the shore.How should  go about achieving this? I want the waves in this pic in motion--> http://www.wallpapervortex.com/wallpaper-23493_beach_sand_sand_beach.html#.U9Rr2fldW8A

Comment: have you thought of using videoview?

Comment: @harvey_slash After going through VideoView class, I believe that is not apt to my requirement. From my understanding , VideoView along with MediaController gives option to pause while I do not require those features.

Answer (score 0):

Have each frame as a seperate image in the drawable folder. After that, use an xml to define the frames(eg, ANIMATED.xml)

```
<animation-list android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/0" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/5" android:duration="50" />
 </animation-list>
```

And to make it animate, use this:

```
// Load the ImageView that will host the animation and
 // set its background to our AnimationDrawable XML resource.
 ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.moving_image);
 img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ANIMATED.xml);

 // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
 AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();

 // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
 frameAnimation.start();
```